# Is the derivative of an integer summation of this type meaningful?

Tags: statistics, derivatives, summation

This is perhaps a daft question, but one that came up in discussion today and elicited different responses, so I thought I'd ask here. Imagine a function with the summation operator, like the arithmetic mean of some vector $x$. For this example, consider $x$ to be composed of an integer number of monotonically increasing elements, so that $x$ is effectively a list of values and **not** a function.

$$A = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}.$$

Now imagine you decided you were doing to remove / add elements in this vector, and wanted to specify how much the mean would change as $n$ changes. Naively, you might just write something like

$$\frac{\partial A}{\partial n} = \frac{-1}{n^2}\sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}.$$

In this is anyway meaningful, or a completely wrong-headed mangling of what one can do with summations? I suspect it's pretty much useless given that the vector itself is not a function, but open to correction!

Comment: The mean isn’t a differentiable function of $n$, so it doesn’t obviously make sense to differentiate it (and if you actually want to compute how it changes when you add / remove elements you can just check that the expression you’ve given produces the wrong answer). But you can smooth the sum: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/

Comment: Really useful, thanks @QiaochuYuan - I presume it's not a differentiable function because it's not continuous everywhere, or is there a more obvious think I'm missing?

Comment: Well, it's not even defined on the real numbers, for starters.